# Move CSS and JS cache folder

Tags: 6, caching, files

I want to move the CSS and JS cache folders (`sites/default/files/css` and `sites/default/files/js` to another place. Is this possible?

I want to do this because I'm planning to have the `files` folder on a remote file system and I think that accessing the CSS and JS from remote would slow down the site.

Edit: I'm using Drupal 6.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying this is the best or correct way to do it, but I think you could use `hook_file_url_alter` to change the url for your script and stylesheets:

```
 function hook_file_url_alter(&$original_uri) {
      // rewrite url for your javascript files
      if(strstr($original_url, 'sites/default/files/your-script.js')) {
          $original_url = 'http://example.com/js/your-script.js';
      }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood your question.

Comment: if (strstr($original_uri, 'sites/default/files/css/')) {
          $original_uri = str_replace('sites/default/files/css/','http://example.com/js/',$original_uri);
      }

Answer (score 1):

Try using [File Aliases](http://drupal.org/project/file_aliases)

> The File Aliases module allows you to use token customizable aliases
>   for your uploaded files, giving you the ability to keep your file
>   system organized as per usual while providing clean looking paths
>   (i.e., no more '/sites/default/files/').

### Features:

- Customizable File Alias field using **Node** tokens.
- Support for:

  - Drupal core Upload module.
  - FileField module.
  - ImageField module.
  - Image module.
  - Comment Upload module.
- Support for Private and Public file systems.
- Support for Views output (Fields and Nodes).
- Support for FileField Paths Retroactive and Active Updating.

### Required Modules:

- FileField Paths (6.14 or greater)